# Find a function with 4 unstable fixed points

Tags: functions, fixed-point-theorems

I need to find a function that has 4 fixed points, and all of them are unstable. I don't know how to proceed in this kind of problem, but i know how to find the fixed points in a function, and i know how to determine if the fixed points are unstable or stable, but i never worked **constructing** a function with $n-$fixed points. I think there is a general way to make those functions, but i don't know it.

Any hints?

Comment: Dose it have to be a continuous function?

Comment: @QthePlatypus isn't neccesary, but if it continuous i think it's harder to find. I'm not sure.

Comment: A trivial solution would be to define your function pair wise so f(1) = 1 f(2) = 2 etc and f(n) = n^2 + 6 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try $f$ of the form $f(x) = x +  c (x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)$.  Now what do you need to be sure that $x_1, \ldots, x_4$ are unstable?

Comment: I can take the derivative, but i don't see how to continue.

Comment: How about, say, $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 2$, $x_3 = 3$, $x_4 = 4$?  Can you find a $c$ that works?